# Can't Add Type Library After Upgrading Project From Visual Studio 2008 to 2012

Tags: c#, winforms, com, reference, typelib

Recently, I converted my Winform project from Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2012 and I am attempting to add a COM type library reference.  The result is the following error message.  Can someone please help me troubleshoot the error?  The upgrade report indicated no errors so, I am not sure where to begin troubleshooting.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to reference from the COM components tab or by browsing?

This page (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wkze6zky.aspx) has some information regarding adding COM components:

"If you want to add a reference to a registered COM DLL that contains an internal manifest, make sure that you unregister the DLL first. If you do not, Visual Studio adds the assembly reference as an ActiveX Component instead of as a native DLL."

Hope this is somewhat helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your post and sorry for the late response.  It ended up being related to my misunderstanding of how to reference the COM components and this article lead me to the correct solution.